# Reusing non-outputted variables of an ODE solver function in subsequent iterations of a solve_ivp solution

Tags: python, performance, optimization, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using solve_ivp. However, the function I use to compute my derivatives makes use of a computationally expensive function, to which I feed a random input as a starting point to get the variable output I want. However, if I used the output of this same function from a previous time step of the ODE solution in the current time step, then it would speed up the overall solution process quite considerably. (I realize my explanation may be messy, so I put a bit of fictitious code to illustrate the problem).

```
from scipy import solve_ivp

def ODE_solver(t, Y):
    #######################################
    ##### Some Calculations performed #####
    #######################################

    n0 = np.random.randn(some_number)
    n = slow_function(n0)
    
    #######################################
    ##### Some Calculations performed #####
    #######################################
    
    return dYdt

sol = solve_ivp(ODE_solver, tspan, ICs)
```

`n0` is created somewhat randomly, which is then used to initialize said function which returns `n`, then used to calculate the derivatives, but is not outputted. The idea would be to use the value of `n` for a given function evaluation as `n0` for the following evaluation during the solve_ivp solution process.

I have thought of using global variables for this, but I am not sure whether there could be a better, more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Does the value of `slow_function` only depend on the random number? Could you just as well make a function table a-priori and then draw randomly from that table?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am not sure I am familiar with function tables. The 'slow_function' does not depend on the random number, as it should eventually converge into the same output regardless, but it will do so faster with the output from a previous time step

Comment: This does not really help. Do you, for example, solve a non-linear system inside the ODE function, and you want to keep the current Jacobian (approximation)? /:/ A function table is just that, an array that contains in its rows the pairs `[n0,n]` and of arbitrary length. Then just randomly generate a row index.

Comment: Try to get an impression of what Butcher tableaux are and look at some of RK4, RKF45, the various DoPri45 variants. Then get an overview impression of what it means that a method is variable step. Then rethink your memory strategy. /:/ And how heavily you or not you violate the smoothness assumptions that the ODE integrators make. An order `p` method requires that the ODE function is `p` times differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for external input to the ODE function:

- `solve_ivp` now supports an `args` argument like in the other solvers,
- you can always use `lambda` constructs to get a partially evaluated function. (`numpy` has a function for partial evaluation?)
- you can make `ODE_solver` (it is not the solver, it is the ODE function or the derivatives function) a class, with the function itself realized in the `__call__` member function. Static data can then be a data member of the class instances, computed or established at initialization. (Supposedly having the derivatives return vector as a fixed member of the class speeds up the solver somewhat.)

Your question can not be finally answered, as that depends on how static or dynamic this data is. But it is always good to identify the routines that are most computation intensive and then try to reduce the number of becalls to them.